# Expose vs exposè

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between the terms:

> **expose** and **exposè**

Is the latter is just French version of the former or its meaning is also varied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Expose** is a verb meaning "reveal, uncover, make visible". **Exposé** is a noun, from French, meaning "a news article, book, movie or electronic report that reveals a hidden truth about someone or something".

They are pronounced differently.

[British pronunciation of **expose**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/expose_1)

[British pronunciation of **exposé**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/expose_2)

Note: the correct accent over the last letter of exposé is an acute accent, not a grave one as you used.

[Expose vs. exposé](https://grammarist.com/usage/expose-vs-expose/)